# Why do we consider that air comes into jet engine?

Tags: jet-engine, jet, compressor, fluid-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

While calculating air pressure and temperature during cruise of jet engines, we consider that air comes into the jet engine inlet with our flight velocity.

But why? In fact, air stops stagnant in atmosphere and aircraft moves with a flight velocity into air.

During calculations, we say: "Static pressure of air is [image: 1], and it has a velocity of flight velocity. Then air comes to rest, so its static pressure increases!".

But the thing I don't understand is actually air doesn't have that velocity, what has that velocity is jet engine/aircraft.

Can you explain this assumption?

Comment: Velocity depends on frame of reference. If you were in the vacuum of space, and an asteroid was flying towards you, from the asteroids perspective it is static and you are flying towards it. Same thing is happening between the plane and the air, you're just using the nearby reference point of the earth to confuse yourself.

Comment: For a turbo-engine what ultimately counts is not the proper velocity of air, nor the velocity of the aircraft, but [air velocity relatively to compressor rotor blades](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/90306/3201) (or fan blades), which spin, that makes a big difference. Note when tests are made in  wind tunnels, this is air which is moving, not the surfaces.

Answer (score 15):

Both the air and the engine are moving very, very fast. Our galaxy and everything in it is moving at a blistering speed of several hundred miles per second.

Of course, we don't feel this speed. Velocity is relative. Try sticking your hand out the window while driving (or flying, if you are brave and your POH permits it). The air pushes against your hand exactly the same as it would if you were sitting in a wind tunnel and your car wasn't moving at all.

This is the only reason wind tunnels are useful to begin with- because velocity is relative, the physics is the same whether the plane is flying through the air or whether it is sitting in a wind tunnel with the air being blown over it.

Comment: "*Our galaxy and everything in it is moving at a blistering speed of several hundred miles per second.*" moving relatively to what? The Universe expands, but there is no center of expansion.

Comment: Actually, if the observable universe is in consideration, I am the center of it.

Comment: @mins It's the peculiar velocity of the Milky Way. Every galaxy would have a particular velocity if the expansion of the universe were perfectly isotropic, and the peculiar velocity is the difference between this velocity and the galaxy's actual velocity. You can also think of it as the velocity relative to the cosmic microwave background. This is the closest thing that the universe has to a rest frame and so the closest thing to an "absolute velocity" we can define. Of course, there is nothing actually privileged about this frame- the point of my answer is that only relative velocities matter

Comment: I originally had some of these details in my draft answer, but I think they detract from the actual point.

Comment: @Chris: In my hubble opinion, you're correct.

Comment: How is the physics the same? By taking the engine as reference frame, we are assuming air that is actually stagnant has dynamic pressure, which increases total pressure of flow. After this, we are doing all calculations based on it, and automatically flow conditions at nozzle are different than ground-based calculations too. In this case, kinetic energy change of the flow is different in jet engine-based reference frame than in ground-based reference frame. What it means? It means we find engine work on flow different for two different reference frames.

Comment: @Jawel7 The general principle is called Galilean relativity. As you've noticed, work done is not a Galilean invariant- the computation of work varies from reference frame to reference frame. The amount of work required to accelerate a mass a specific amount varies between reference frames by the same amount, so this cancels out, and no quantity that matters physically differs between the reference frames. The impulse on the air, and thus the engine's thrust, is a Galilean invariant and you will compute the same result in any frame.

Comment: @Chris-RegenerateResponse for thrust point of view, you are definitely right. However, we get the same understanding for energy of fluid as well, as I explained in my previous comment. So in this case, don't we get wrong values for energy point of view by getting the engine as reference frame instead of ground? Kinetic energy difference of the fluid, work done on the fluid by the engine, differs from frame to frame.

Comment: @Jawel7 Kinetic energy varies as the square of the speed, so the difference in energy of the fluid is indeed different from reference frame to reference frame. Not every reference frame agrees on the value of every variable. But you can do the analysis in any frame you like, and then use a Galilean transform to figure out what variables would be measured in any *other* reference frame without doing the whole analysis over. Conveniently, force is Galilean invariant, so every frame agrees on the actual number. Kinetic energy is not, so if you want to know that in another frame you need to ...

Comment: find it in one frame and then apply a Galilean transform to find it in another frame. It's not "wrong," it's just "different." Just like airspeed and groundspeed are different- they are just the speed measured in different reference frames, both are equally valid even though the number is different.

Answer (score 11):

Because it doesn't affect the math, and because it helps with keeping relative change in perspective if we use the engine as a frame of reference instead of the airmass.

Also because you are incorrect in assuming that air "stops stagnant in the atmosphere". The air is in constant motion and has velocity relative to the earth.  However, if we used a fixed earth reference then we'd have to account for wind in our calculations and that would complicate things unnecessarily. (*because where do you stop?  i.e. what about planetary motion?!*)

We all understand that outside of a wind tunnel it is actually the engine that is moving, but it just makes a lot more sense to keep things simple and consider the engine as a stationary reference for doing things like describing the function of an engine and calculating airflow.

Comment: Whether the engine is moving is a matter of choice, both inside and outside the wind tunnel. Motion is relative and no reference frame is better than any other (well, reference frames in free fall are a bit better, but on the Earth those don't tend to be co-moving with anything useful).

Comment: @JanHudec, I disagree completely that "no reference frame is better than any other" for the reasons given in my answer.  Consider the verbal gymnastics needed if you used ground track with a stiff crosswind as your reference when explaining the path of airflow through a centrifugal flow compressor.  Why not eliminate unneeded variables?

Comment: Well, we have to distinguish between *better for describing particular situation* and *“always” better*. The former definitely exists (and is the reference frame attached to the engine in this particular case, which is the point here). The later does not, that's the whole point of relativity.

Comment: I didn’t use the term “always”.  I’m generally pretty careful to avoid absolute statements unless they are “always” true.  Your statement “no reference frame is better than any other” is pretty absolute, despite the exception in parenthesis.  I’m always open to constructive feedback for improving my answers, but I don’t see anything helpful I can actually use in this.  Unless you can offer a more specific suggestion?

Comment: I quite like the answer as written (and upvoted it before I even wrote that comment). I only commented—and admit I was very unclear—the bit that the engine ‘is actually moving’. You can always choose a reference frame in which they are moving, but it isn't actual, it's still just a choice, and it would be a bad choice here.

Comment: Jan - I'm afraid I have to agree your comments (in this case) came off a bit muddled!    In your sentence *" ... is better than any other  .."* you're referring to what we all learned in junior high (primary, out side the US  :) :) :) ) which has no connection to this answer's use of "better".  BTW, note too that *"Whether the engine is moving is a matter of choice, both inside and outside the wind tunnel"* is very confusing, it's incredibly hard / impossible to make an engine in a wind tunnel move, ie have any velocity (ie, compared to the building) for more than split-seconds.

Comment: @MichaelHall: In this context, "better" is (probably) not being used to mean "more useful," but rather to mean "more *correct.*" And it is absolutely true that no reference frame is more *correct* than any other reference frame. That probably seems like an obvious truism to you, but it can be a bit of a revelation for physics students who have not yet encountered it.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to the last question is "Galilean relativity", the assumption that the same laws of physics hold in any inertial frame of reference. In the example, it is presumably easier to do the analysis in the engine's frame of reference.

Comment: Welcome, you win for succinct!

Answer (score 4):

Our universe is so constructed that it doesn't matter if the air is moving and the model is standing still, or if the model is moving and the air is standing still. In either case, *air is coming into the jet engine*.

Note also that when a jet-powered plane is operating at its design point for cruise conditions, the air right inside the engine inlet is moving at the same speed as the air just outside the inlet. That is, the streamlines of air parcels entering the engine are not perturbed by the engine cowling. There is no *spillage* nor *suction* effects at design point cruise.